# Error upgrading to Kotlin 1.2.60, Android Studio 3.1.3

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, realm

Pretext: I have 3 build variants for my project apart from release and debug I also have the staging variant.

Gradle sync works completely fine with version 1.2.51, but as soon as I upgrade to version 1.2.60, which released recently, gradle sync fails with the following error message:

> Could not find method kapt() for arguments
> [build_9jdgbsb8xiz9dkrq42qtcg5eg$_run_closure1$_closure6@576656b5] on
> object of type com.android.build.gradle.LibraryExtension.

Any help/ insight on this would be really great, I tried searching for a while, but was stuck on what to search exactly, what I think could be the issue here is the `kapt` plugin as the changelog mentions changes in it, chec [this](https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2018/08/kotlin-1-2-60-is-out/), but couldn't get it running.

#### Dependecies:

Top level gradle:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-alpha03'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:$realm_version"
        classpath 'com.akaita.android:easylauncher:1.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.5'
    }
```

App level:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
```

PS: I'm on Gradle plugin 4.9, Studio 3.1.3 and android gradle plugin 3.3.0-alpha03.

Thank you.

Comment: can u add build.gradle file

Comment: which one, the application level or project level? Also what parts of it would be of interest to you, i've some scripts on it as well, can definitely exclude them.

Comment: Dependencies part and apply plugin parts

Comment: It follow maybe not be helpfull to you but, it isn't recommended the use of `alpha dependencies`, maybe the use of `beta` but `alpha` not

Comment: @AbnerEscócio tried, didn't help much

Comment: @Redman, added deps.

Comment: What is your Realm version?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce realm version here is: 5.4.0,

Comment: Hmm. I guess that shouldn't cause problems if you don't have `experimental = true` on the android extensions. Otherwise you'd have to use 5.5.0-SNAPSHOT for the transformer

Comment: yep, that's what i thought as well. But realm has nothing to do here, i can confirm that. it's something to do with the compiler i think, specially `kapt`. Since it's pretty new, can't find much doc for the same.

Comment: Kotlin 1.2.60 released last night . The best option I can suggest right now you can test with Android Studio 3.3 Canary Build .

You can check with KOTLIN 1.2.60 BLOG as many users already facing issues with KAPT on latest update .

I suggest you should downgrade kotlin with last stable version 1.2.51 and wait for android studio till they start supporting Kotlin 1.2.60 . It happened with me when I was upgraded kotlin to 1.2.51(Always make sure you are using latest Android Studio(Canary build or Beta) along with latest Kotlin version) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to this, in case anyone struggles with it,

### The problem:

I had a module dependency, which was using some `kapt` methods but hadn't included

`apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in it's project level `build.gradle` file.

I added it and voila, it works.